# How to change DataGridView Background color/ Cell Color

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

Is there a way to change the color of the DataGridView from white to something else to match my color theme?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Under your DataGridView you have `DefaultCellStyle` -> `BackColor`.

You can change that to the color that you like.

There is also a `SelectionBackColor` if you need that.

Comment: Thank you... This was very useful

Answer (score 0):

> using `DefaultCellStyle` property for change datagridview cell
>   backcolor and forecolor.

```
this.dataGridView1.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#292c33");
this.dataGridView1.DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#FFFFFF");
```

if you want to change the cell SelectionBackColor and SelectionForeColor.

```
this.dataGridView1.DefaultCellStyle.SelectionBackColor =yourSelectionBackcolor;
this.dataGridView1.DefaultCellStyle.SelectionForeColor =yourSelectionForecolor;
```

Comment: Is there any way to change the color of the header and the Selection column (the one to the left from EMP_ID)?

Comment: @jbegic I don't think that you can change that. Your best bet would be to use a custom control.

Comment: @jbegic, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/customize-cells-and-columns-in-the-datagrid-by-extending-behavior

Comment: @VigneshNethaji - Thank you